# Usage of "will" twice in a sentence

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, redundancy

Is it wrong if I say like

> Shyam **will** decide that he **will** work hard for the upcoming exams and come first in class.

Is there any rule that we shouldn't use **will** twice in a sentence?

If so, which one should I drop?

Does simple present work here in the place of *will decide*?

And is the sentence above correct grammatically?

Could you please explain to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's  no rule against using the same  auxiliary verb, including *will*, more than once in a sentence.

Consider these two  examples, written by native speakers, found in a search for ["will decide that he will"](https://www.google.com/search?q="will+decide+that+he+will"):

> My husband, who is a pediatrician, still holds on to a hope that *Adrian, one of our youngest, will decide that he will do it after all*.

([source](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/changingthefaceofmedicine/physicians/biography_70.html))

and

> It may well be that the circumstances are such that *the franchisor will decide that he will terminate the contract...*

([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=v_RandLSSDAC&pg=PA102&lpg=PA102&dq="will+decide+that+he+will"&source=bl&ots=1sYl-rmuTS&sig=DWmS3iEhDEHioTfHco65Oqwf1VU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHloicqrfPAhXH7yYKHURVCQwQ6AEIHjAB#v=onepage&q=%22will%20decide%20that%20he%20will%22&f=false))

In fact, you could have used it three times by using *will* before *come*, but it's probably better to avoid that much repetition.

So there is nothing wrong with your sentence grammatically.

You could use the simple present instead of the first *future will*, as in

> Shyam  decides that he will work hard for the upcoming exams and come first in class.

but without a context that makes it clear that you are talking about the future, using *future will* seems better; by using  *future will* in your sentence it  is much clearer that you are talking about future time.

I call *will* in your sentence *future will* because the modal verb *will* has other uses than to talk about future time.

Comment: But the test which I've taken claims that **will** is wrong here. And it didn't provide any context. Just it had given the sentence and asked me to find the error. So, this sentence is perfectly right without context. Right?

Comment: Possibly *come* should be *will come* since that's happening in the future too.

Comment: @LawrenceC I thought so. That's where I pointed out the error. But the test claims something else.

Comment: Maybe remove the first 'will.'  It's not grammatically wrong, but you are saying that in the future you will make a decision to do X in the future, rather than simply make a decision to do X in the future.  So it sounds needlessly indirect.

Comment: @LawrenceC It's not grammatically wrong. So, the test might be wrong here.

Comment: If you click on the tag exam-question you'll find many (almost all?) test questions to be wrong in some way. Also, we don't know what the exam is testing you on: unless we know that, it's hard to judge the test.

Comment: @AlanCarmack It just asked me to find the error in the sentence. And it didn't say any further.